Extract editable text from patents with drawings
I have a bunch of scanned images of patents which I need to convert somehow into some editable form (docx preferrably). Here is an example of one page:

I extracted the text using tesseract successfuly (almost, I have issues extracting latin symbols and subscript) but I have no idea how to aproach extracting drawings from text. Have tried to use OpenCv's canny edge detection but without success.
Is there some go to method for such tasks? May be train yolo or some other CNN or use other algorithm from opencv?
I would really appreciate if someone share their experience

there is commercial and free software for turning scans into editable documents. those also try to spot graphics and maintain those as graphics.

Google's Cloud Vision OCR is the best I'm aware of for this type of extraction: https://cloud.google.com/use-cases/ocr

@JeshuaLacock There are sensitive information in those docs, I can’t upload them to the cloud, need something to deploy locally

@ChristophRackwitz any example of OSS of this kind?

Training a YOLO network is definitely a simple job to perform this task.  This is very close to what I do at work.  I have some tutorial videos showing how to train neural networks to find text, images, checkboxes, and more.  Here is one of many such tutorials I publish on my channel:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxhbXccHEpA
In my case, I use libpoppler to convert the PDF documents to PNG images.  One image per page.  Then Darknet/YOLO to scan each image, extracting everything I need.
With the sample image you posted, the pages and images are very repetitive, so I would guess it would take ~30 minutes max to train a network, and likely more like 15 minutes if you have a decent NVIDIA GPU.
If you'd like to try it, I suggest start here with the FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#how_to_get_started
The other resource to check out is the Darknet/YOLO discord server:  https://discord.gg/zSq8rtW

Link-only answers are not valid answers. Also, this doesn't answer anything specifically - it promotes some video training. Please don't answer off-topic questions seeking recommendations.

It is a good thing I didn't provide a link-only answer!
